# Why in Firebase Analytics Conversion (not set) is showing on Firebase dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-ads-api

Android code for sending data to firebase analytics:-

```
FirebaseAnalytics logger = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(activity);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Type", type);
logger.logEvent("RazorPay", bundle);
```

This event is correctly recorded in Firebase Analytics but in Campaign section it have displayed as (not set)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8E7i.png

I have also check log in Firebase debug view all data are correctly recorded
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfZ1Z.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi3Uy.png)

Does anyone understand what wrong is going here, why display (not set) value?, what exactly show instead of (not set)

Thank you in advance